# Show full error messages with simple form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

How do I output the full error message of a field using simple form? The equivalent of rails: `<%= RESOURCE.errors.full_messages %>`

e.g. show this:

```
"Email has already been taken", 
"Password confirmation doesn't match Password", 
"Password is too short (minimum is 8 characters)"
```

instead of: `f.error_notification`

```
"has already been taken", 
"doesn't match Password", 
"is too short (minimum is 8 characters)"
```

*simple_form (3.0.2)/Rails 4.1.1*

Comment: Would love to know the answer to this too!

Comment: I cheated. I couldn't make it work. So I disabled their auto error in the initializer and inserted f.full_error :token under each field. Though it works, I still rather have the auto version work....

Answer (score 7):

If anyone is still wondering there is an easy way to do this now, as referenced [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/pull/909#issuecomment-38210976)

Simply under `config/initializers/simple_form.rb` change `b.user :error` to `b.user :full_error` and now your error messages will be the equivalent of `RESOURCE.errors.full_messages`

Note: if you are using bootstrap w/ simple form you change `simple_form_bootstrap.rb`

Comment: I think you should add some emphasis on changing `simple_form_bootstrap.rb` for those using bootstrap

Comment: Note that the line is `b.use :error`, and not `b.user :error`