# Show full messages on simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, simple-form

I'm having this form

```
<%= simple_form_for :post do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.input :body %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

The title field in my example is required. So if I try and submit the form without any value in the `:title`, the validation fails and comes back with an error message, as expected. However the error I get by default is just this `can't be blank`, so I was wondering if there's a way to display the full message of validation errors (like when not using `simple_form` gem), like `The title field can't be blank` etc

Is there a way t display the full messages?

Comment: on top or inline errors?

Comment: @Sajan I believe that's not the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon inspection, I found out that you can configure this globally:

**config/initializers/simple_form.rb**

```
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  config.wrappers :default, class: :input,
    hint_class: :field_with_hint, error_class: :field_with_errors do |b|
    # ...
    # ...
    # COMMENT THIS LINE JUST LIKE THIS:
    # b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :error }

    # THEN UNCOMMENT THIS LINE JUST LIKE THIS:
    b.use :full_error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :error }
  end
end
```

*Tested working.*

Comment: As per this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24358068/show-full-error-messages-with-simple-form, I had to edit the `initializers/simple_form_bootstrap.rb` as I'm using Bootstrap. I'll accept you answer as correct as it works on simple_form as stand alone and because it helped me to find out the solution. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Not very clean, but it works :)

```
<%= simple_form_for :post do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>
  <%= f.input :title, error: f.object.errors.full_messages_for(:title).to_sentence %>
  <%= f.input :body, error: f.object.errors.full_messages_for(:body).to_sentence %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Both solutions work fine but, Is there a "global" config setting, because right now I have to do it on every single form

Comment: @Lykos I just added a new answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using the full_error method, something like this:

```
<%= f.input :title, error: f.full_error(:title) %>
```

Comment: This works fine but, Is there a "global" config setting, because right now I have to do it on every single form